# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

[image]

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)

Comment: You should add some code and explain what are you going to do and at which line this error happens

Comment: Based on the error message, I'm not really sure what might be gleaned from seeing his code. It looks like it's complaining that the EF DLL doesn't have the right signature. Perhaps the key specified in the app/web config file doesn't match that of the version of EF installed?

Comment: Thank you for your Comments I have already try that by Reinstalling EF but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the EntityFramework* references from your solution and then reinstalling Entity Framework into your solution using the Nuget package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with localhost debug - Clean/Rebuild doesnt helped
After some research i found and copied required framework  file to path - Problem solved

Please check your path in error message
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\0a4baecb\876745ee

Copy Paste file EntityFramework.DLL
And make it readonly!

DONE